# Good resources for web form design and usability

Tags: web-development, design, gui-design, usability

Can anyone suggest good resources about web form design and usability for web applications?
Especially complex forms with 15+ fields etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A List Apart has a great article on [user interface design](http://www.alistapart.com/topics/design/userinterfacedesign/) and [sensible forms](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sensibleforms).

Comment: +1, both are excellent articles from an excellent source.

Answer (score 7):

I was inspired by a [list of 36 login forms](http://dzineblog.com/2009/03/interface-design-inspiration-36-beautiful-login-pageform-designs.html) to rethink how I went about my form design.

- A touch of style goes a long way
- You don't need to make them tiny, larger text is more readable
- Simple and most importantly *clear* validation errors / messages

There is also a great article on [15+ best practices for form design](http://www.admixweb.com/2009/12/22/15-best-practices-tips-designing-web-form/) on AdmixWeb.

Comment: I like the `function LoginPage()` one. Geek to the core! good example site.

Comment: @Michael: It is, unfortunately the site is broken, exposing a lot of Django underpinnings.

Answer (score 4):

Anything by [Luke Wroblewski](http://www.lukew.com/ff/) and I would seriously recommend getting his book [Web Form Design: Filling in the Blanks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1933820241).

The link I posted to Luke's website contains all his writings, which is not focused just on form design. The following [link](http://www.lukew.com/ff/archive.asp?tag&forms) is a collection of all the articles that deal with forms - 154 articles.

Comment: You can watch a presentation of him at the Mix 2010  conference:
http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/EX03

Answer (score 2):

In general some good reading.

[SmashingMagazine Posts Tagged ‘usability’](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/tag/usability/)

And here comes some other post.

- [Web Form Design Patterns: Sign-Up Forms](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/07/04/web-form-design-patterns-sign-up-forms/)
- [CSS-Based Forms: Modern Solutions](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2006/11/11/css-based-forms-modern-solutions/)
- [Web Form Validation: Best Practices and Tutorials](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/07/web-form-validation-best-practices-and-tutorials/)